# Allowing to click on a link after script has finished running

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Im trying to find a way to allow user to click on the link only after a specific function has completed running. So here in my case I have ejs template where there are two links in parapgraphs. Clicking on the first one ("Run python") activates a script that takes some time to complete. Then only after it has finished (so the there is **"finished"** - which comes from the line: `console.log('finished'`) printed on the console) the next link("See the table") would be clickable (or unhid or something like that).

```
<h1>Search for a movie</h1>

<form action="results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search term" name="search">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><a href="/run"> Run python </a></p>
<p><a href="/data"> See the table </a></p>
```

Here is the app.js code

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var request = require("request")
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

var thelist =[]

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("search")
})

var jsondata = ""


app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    var query = req.query.search
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&type=series&apikey=thewdb"

    request(url, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(body)
            res.render("results", {data: data})
        }    
    })
})

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    //viewname can include or omit the filename extension
    res.render(__dirname + '/well.html'); 
});


app.get("/show/:id", function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    thelist.push(id)
    console.log(thelist);
    res.redirect('/')
});

app.get("/run", function(req, res) {
            var pyshell = new PythonShell('script2.py');
            pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(thelist))
            pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
            jsondata += message
            });

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
            pyshell.end(function (err) {
             if (err){
               throw err;
                };

            console.log('finished');
            });
            res.redirect('/')
            thelist = []
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Movie App has started!!!");
})
```

Comment: Say you keep that link ("See the table") initially hidden (or disabled), then add an inline style to it within the `pyshell.end` function after the `console.log('finished')`, does that work? **e.g:** `var linkToEnable = document.querySelector(".link-to-enable);
linkToEnable.style.display = "block";` (just an example - the point here is to determine if you can add an inline style at the intended moment: after function in question has completed)

Comment: Hmm im not sure if im doing it corectly, but i get error that document is not defined. This is server side node.js code and it doesnt seem to allow dom manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do it with ajax, as emil suggests in his answer,
but since you are using *ejs* template engine, why don't use it ?
(You just need to change the `.html` template file extension to `.ejs`).

Also, I think your best option here is to not use `res.redirect`.
It would be better to use `res.render` and pass a parameter to the view, set to `false` by default.

A basic example:

server.js

```
// ...
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("search", { active: false });
})

// ...
app.get("/run", function (req, res) {
  // ...
  pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('finished');
    res.render("search", { active: true });
  });
});
```

search.ejs

```
<p><a href="/run">Run python</a></p>
<p>
  <%if (active) { %>
    <a href="/data">See the table</a>
  <% } else { %>
    See the table
  <% } %>
</p>
```

Now the `See the table` link is only clickable if the python script is finish.

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

It should be done by using AJAX calls. Instead of using redirect in `/run`, you can make it return some JSON data which indicates success/error state of the job.

On click of `Run python`, it will run AJAX call instead of redirecting page to `/`.

on `OnSuccess` of AJAX call, you can enable see the table.

**Code**

HTML

```
<p><a id="run" href="/run"> Run python </a></p>
<p><a id="show-data" href="/data" style="pointer-events:none;"> See the table </a></p>
```

Frontend Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('#run').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.get('/run', function() {
       $('#show-data').css('pointer-events', 'all');
     });
  });
});
```

NodeJs

```
app.get("/run", function(req, res) {
  ...
  // res.redirect('/');
  res.json({ success: true });
});
```

Comment: I tried this as you posted and the "See the table" is already clickable just after I click on run python, but the script havent finished yet. Why is that so?

Comment: In other words it should send res.json({success: true}) after the whole code in app.get has run- so the console.log was excuted.

Comment: Yes of course. `res.json` should be called after app.get has finished all its job, which means it should be at the end of promise chain or in last callback fired.

Comment: But that is what Im doing now. I inserted res.json below the console.log('finished') line. However it still runs before the console.log is printed

Comment: Did you remove `res.redirect('/')` on run function?

Comment: Yes I did that: currently it looks like this: 
`app.get("/run", function(req, res) {
            var pyshell = new PythonShell('script2.py');
            pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(thelist))
            pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
            jsondata += message
            });
            pyshell.end(function (err) {
             if (err){
               throw err;
                };
            console.log(jsondata);
            res.json({ success: true });
            });
});`

Comment: What do you get on AJAX call if you try `res.json(jsonData)`?

Comment: Im not sure if this what you are asknig for: 
`jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "https://python-node-projct-atpim.c9users.io/run?onSuccess=undefined".
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):94
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3`
I get this after the actual console.log statement ran- so it printed what i wanted. However the link "Run the table" is clickable before this is received and the console.log is printed.

Answer (score 1):

U can prevent links by using prevent function Jquery

```
 $("a").click(function() {
        if (status == "1") {
           return true;

        } else {
           return false;
           e.preventDefault();
        }
     });
```

This is the function where I used to stop the user from navigating to other pages without running a function.

I Initialized a variable called status with value = 0

Then I incremented the variable once the function was success.

So if the status is 0 then the URL won't work, after finishing the function the status will be incremented to 1 and hence if the condition is true and it will return true statement. If not it will return false statement and it will be prevented using e.preventDefault()

Comment: This is the easy part of the question. But the other part how it'll set the status ;) ?

Comment: u have to increment the status value after the successful completion of your function,

Comment: would you mind adding this part of the code to your solution?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try socket.io?
Here is simplified code, but fully functional...

(Note: "msg" object is for example only, for further usage)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Search for a movie</h1>
  <p><a href="#" onclick="runPython()"> Run python </a></p>
  <p><a id="table-data"> See the table </a></p>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var msg = {
      msg: "TestMsgSend",
      iParam: 100,
      sParam: "Test Param 1",
      aParam: [1, 2, 3]
    }
    var socket = io();

    socket.on("server:finished", function (msg) {
      // msg = "TestMsgReceived", for further usage
      console.log("\nId: " + socket.id + "\nmsg: " + msg.msg + "\niParam: " + msg.iParam + "\nsParam: " + msg.sParam + "\naParam: " + msg.aParam);

      document.getElementById("table-data").setAttribute("href", "/data");
    });

    function runPython() {
      socket.emit("client:run", msg);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/"));

// ***************************************************************************
// ***************************************************************************
// ***** Your code
// ***************************************************************************
// ***************************************************************************

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("New connection with id: " + socket.id);

  socket.on("client:run", function (msg) {
    // msg = "TestMsgSend", for further usage
    console.log("\nId: " + socket.id + "\nmsg: " + msg.msg + "\niParam: " + msg.iParam + "\nsParam: " + msg.sParam + "\naParam: " + msg.aParam);

    // ***************************************************************************
    // ***************************************************************************
    // ***** Your code
    // ***************************************************************************
    // ***************************************************************************

    msg.msg = "TestMsgReceived";
    msg.iParam++;
    msg.sParam = "Test Param 2";
    msg.aParam.push(4, 5, 6)
    io.emit("server:finished", msg);
  });
});

// ***************************************************************************
// ***************************************************************************
// ***** Your code
// ***************************************************************************
// ***************************************************************************

http.listen(80, function () {
  console.log("listening on *:80");
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Start with **node app.js** and enjoy

Comment: Implementing sockets for this use case is overkilling. You're not making a real-time app. It's just disabling a link!

Answer (score -1):

Why not something like a simple guard variable? In your code:

```
var ready = false; // 1) the guard

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    if (ready) { // 2) view execution blocked until guard is ready
        res.render(__dirname + '/well.html');
    }
});

app.get("/run", function(req, res) {
    var pyshell = new PythonShell('script2.py');
    pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(thelist))
    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
        // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
        jsondata += message
    });

    // end the input stream and allow the process to exit
    pyshell.end(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        };
        ready = true; // 3) if evetything is OK the guard is now ready
        console.log('finished');
    });
    res.redirect('/')
    thelist = []
});
```

Comment: 1- Using a global variable for a single threaded server would never properly with multiple users.
2- This doesn't answer the question to disable the link.